# Manage routes by roles cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, routes, roles

I'm working on cakephp project. I have problem but don't know how to resolve it.
I have variable store in Session call is 'roles'. And I have some routes are manage by this roles but denied with other roles. So how can I config routes by roles like this. Give me a tips. Thank you so much

Sample maybe I want like this

```
if($this->Session->read("role")=="admin"){
   allow("/admin/dashboard");
}else{
   denied("/admin/dashboard");
}

if($this->Session->read("role")=="staff"){
  allow("/staff/dashboard");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ello, mate.

Are you using the Auth component to authenticate logins? if you're using it, you can allow and deny controller actions with:

```
//AdminController
$this->Auth->allow('dashboard'); //Allow the dashboard method on admin controller
$this->Auth->deny('dashboard'); //Deny the dashboard method on admin controller
```

You can also make conditions on beforeFilter() to redirect it based on the role:

```
//ExampleController
public function beforeFilter()
{
     if($this->Session->read("role")=="admin")
     {
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'yo_controller', 'action' => 'yo_action'));
     }
     //.......
}
```

If you want, have a look on the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authorization) about authorization, it may help you.